# How can I do a column select across the entire file?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a way I can use the middle click or maybe (***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>***) to a particular column across all lines in a long file? Currently, I am middle-clicking and then dragging this to the end of the screen and waiting for it to select all lines.

Specifically, for long files, how would I select one particular column across the entire file?

Comment: Not sure about sublimetext, but several editors lets you do this by doing a click on the beginning of the column and pressing alt+shift to mark your column.

Comment: @EmmadKareem: Thank you. I just tried it but unfortunately, it does not seem to work in Sublime.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html

Comment: @EmmadKareem: Unless I am missing something, that page only explains how to use Ctrl but what I want is to select all lines in a file. Adding a block using Ctrl will still require me to hold onto the mouse selection.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, sorry I could not help.

Comment: @EmmadKareem: Oh.. Thank you for your time :) Hopefully someone can give me a hint.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

This should do it:

1. `Ctrl+A` - select all.
2. `Ctrl+Shift+L` - split selection into lines.
3. Then move all cursors with `left/right`, select with `Shift+left/right`. Move all cursors to start of line with `Home`.

Comment: This should do it:

Cmd+A - select all.
Cmd+Shift+L - split selection into lines.
Then move all cursors with left/right, select with Shift+left/right. Move all cursurs to start of line with Home.

Comment: @Justin: Thank you. I guess this is for a Mac system.

Comment: On Mac, if you don't have a "Home" button available you can hit `Ctrl-A` to move all the cursors to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 4):

In Mac OS X, replace Ctrl with CMD key. So it'll be,

CMD+A - select all.
CMD+Shift+L - split selection into lines.
Then move all cursors with left/right, select with Shift+left/right. Move all cursors to start of line with Home.

Answer (score 4):

**OS X**

You can click the following and drag to create a selection of one or more columns of characters:

- Left mouse button + `option`
- Middle mouse button

To add to an existing selection, hold `command` while doing the above.

To subtract from an existing selection, hold `command + shift` while doing the above

**Windows**

You can click the following and drag to create a selection of one or more columns of characters:

- Right Mouse Button + `shift`
- Middle Mouse Button

To add to an existing selection, hold `Ctrl` while doing the above.

To subtract from an existing selection, hold `Alt` while doing the above.